# Following the "Getting Started" page doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Following the steps on the page: http://dotnet.github.io/core/getting-started/ on an elevated PowerShell console (Windows 10):

```
&{$Branch='dev';iex ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1'))}
```

downloads and installs correctly.

```
dnvm install -r coreclr latest -u
```

returns error:

```
Determining latest version
Unable to find any runtime packages on the feed!
At C:\Users\softw\.dnx\bin\dnvm.ps1:552 char:9
+         throw "Unable to find any runtime packages on the feed!"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Unable to find ...es on the feed!:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to find any runtime packages on the feed!
```

I managed to get it working by running `dmvm list` and following the offer to install dmx.

Was I doing something wrong or is the documentation out of date?

Comment: I had the same problem. Problem here was that I used a "v3" url instead of "v2". I used this before running the command: `set DNX_UNSTABLE_FEED=https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v2`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `latest` from your command:

```
dnvm install -r coreclr -u
```

Remove `-u` if you want the latest stable bits. `-u` means unstable/dev feed.